# Focus on AutoCompleteTextView does not display soft keyboard on Android TV devices

Tags: android, android-tv

**On Android TV devices**
The soft keyboard does not show when the following AutoCompleteTextView is selected by a remote:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/actvName"
    style="@style/EditText"
    android:hint="@string/name"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/actvAddress"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:text="@={newActivity.ofName}">
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

If AutoCompleteTextView is changed EditText, the keyboard will show up perfectly:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/actvName"
    style="@style/EditText"
    android:hint="@string/name"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/actvAddress"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:text="@={newActivity.ofName}">
</EditText>
```

On **Android phones or tablets**, both EditText and AutoCompleteTextView with **exactly the same code** will trigger the display of keyboard when they get the focus (apparently no remote is involved).

Could anyone offer a tip on how to make AutoCompleteTextView trigger the display of keyboard automatically without writing any event handling java code?

Comment: Did you get any way to get this working?

Comment: @CSG0811 No.  I gave up and have not tried AutoCompleteTextView for a while.

Comment: Thanks @Hong. Even I took a workaround. I did it with EditText and RecyclerView.